# InvalidOperationException error when loading the data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to load data from a database using Entity Framework and ASP.NET MVC. But I got an `InvalidOperationException` error. How to fix this?

I've tried to use tables with and without null data. But none of those work.

```
// Customers controller
public ViewResult Index()
{
    var customers = _context.Customers
                            .Include(c => c.MembershipType).ToList();
}

// Customer model class
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSubscribedToNewsletter { get; set; }
    public MembershipType MembershipType { get; set; }
    public byte MembershipTypeId { get; set; }

    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
}

// Customer view (index.cshtml)
```

It should displays the customers list. But when executing I got this error in customer controller.

Comment: Strange FK type - `public` **byte** `MembershipTypeId`

Comment: Did you cut out some part of your code? Your view result isn't even returning the view.

Comment: I didn't I got this example from a YouTube video. It worked for him. But not for me :( step by step asp net mvc tutorial for beginners part 2 by Mosh https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FTE4mM64cVY&t=4s